# Convert an HDRI background from polyhaven to a Background obj file in Blender

Tags: hdri, obj

I need to convert/access obj files of polyhaven HDRIs using Blender. What are the steps to these preferably without the need for buying their pluggin?

As part of a script, I need the backgrounds to be object files.

```
images = list(Path('/home/mona/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/data/backgrounds').rglob('*.png')) +  list(Path(' /home/mona/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/data/backgrounds').rglob('*.jpg'))
print('background images: ', images)
parts = ['mainshell', 'topshell', 'insert_mold', 'usb_c', 'female_usb', '55917-700lf']
obj_queue = []
for obj in Path("./CAD_model/models").rglob('*.obj'):
    print('obj.name: ', obj.name)
    if 'background' in obj.name:
        print('background in obj name: ', obj.name)
        # print(f'Skipping loading part {obj.name}')

        background = bproc.loader.load_obj(str(obj)).pop()
        background.set_cp("category_id", 0)
        pose = np.eye(4)
        pose[:, 3] = np.array([0, 0, 0-0.01, 1]).T
        background.set_scale([1, 1, 1])
        background.set_local2world_mat(pose)
        background.enable_rigidbody(active=False, collision_shape="CONVEX_HULL")
        image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath=str(random.choice(images)))

        for m in background.get_materials():
            m.set_principled_shader_value('Base Color', image)
```

currently, here are some of the HDRI backgrounds downloaded and converted to png (using https://github.com/agmmnn/polydown ) `$ polydown hdris`

```
(blenderproc) mona@ada:~/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/data/backgrounds$ ls
total 239M
drwxrwxr-x 3 mona mona 4.0K Dec  5 15:08 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.6M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.7M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.2M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_church_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.0M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_church_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.6M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_construction_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.0M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_construction_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.9M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_factory_canteen_01_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.9M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_factory_canteen_01_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.1M Dec  6 10:01 abandoned_factory_canteen_02_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.8M Dec  6 10:01 abandoned_factory_canteen_02_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.7M Dec  6 10:01 abandoned_games_room_01_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.9M Dec  6 10:01 abandoned_games_room_01_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.7M Dec  6 10:01 abandoned_games_room_02_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.1M Dec  6 10:01 abandoned_games_room_02_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.6M Dec  6 10:02 abandoned_greenhouse_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.0M Dec  6 10:02 abandoned_greenhouse_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.5M Dec  6 10:03 abandoned_hall_01_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.0M Dec  6 10:03 abandoned_hall_01_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.6M Dec  6 10:03 abandoned_hopper_terminal_01_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 2.0M Dec  6 10:03 abandoned_hopper_terminal_01_renders_lone_monk.png
```

Also, here is an example of stuff downloaded by polyhaven pip library:

```
(blenderproc) mona@ada:~/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/bg$ ls
total 35G
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 1.7M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_1k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 6.6M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_2k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  26M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_4k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  99M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_8k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 372M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_16k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 1.4M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_thumb.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 2.6M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_primary.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 1.7M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_bakery_renders_lone_monk.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 1.7M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_church_1k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 6.6M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_church_2k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  26M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_church_4k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 102M Dec  6 09:59 abandoned_church_8k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 384M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_church_16k.hdr
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 888K Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_church_thumb.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 2.2M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_church_primary.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 2.0M Dec  6 10:00 abandoned_church_renders_lone_monk.png
```

You can also check the original code which makes use of this request here: https://github.com/yangfei4/BlenderProc2_Cobot/blob/ea97fccf022fdcfb71957ed8656438b5732ca432/main_rand.py#L55

Update:

just a followup, I created an object and made it like this but it seems the board is crashing to it

[image: Screenshot from 2023-12-06 13-05-17]

[image: Screenshot from 2023-12-06 13-11-00]

[image: Screenshot from 2023-12-06 13-11-56]

somehow the method below is not making the pose correct such that the april tag board is laid out on top of it. Could you please suggest a fix?

```
images = list(Path('/home/mona/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/data/backgrounds').rglob('*.png')) +  list(Path(' /home/mona/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/data/backgrounds').rglob('*.jpg'))
print('background images: ', images)
parts = ['mainshell', 'topshell', 'insert_mold', 'usb_c', 'female_usb', '55917-700lf']
obj_queue = []
for obj in Path("./CAD_model/models").rglob('*.obj'):
    print('obj.name: ', obj.name)
    if 'background' in obj.name:
        print('background in obj name: ', obj.name)
        # print(f'Skipping loading part {obj.name}')
        print('dir(obj): ', dir(obj))

        background = bproc.loader.load_obj(str(obj)).pop()
        background.set_cp("category_id", 0)
        pose = np.eye(4)
        pose[:, 3] = np.array([0, 0, 0-0.01, 1]).T
        background.set_scale([1, 1, 1])
        background.set_local2world_mat(pose)
        background.enable_rigidbody(active=False, collision_shape="CONVEX_HULL")
        image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath=str(random.choice(images)))

        for m in background.get_materials():
            print('material in background is: ', m)
            m.set_principled_shader_value('Base Color', image)

        continue

    ## TODO(yangfei): should assign each part with unique id?  e.g. mainshell_00
    for _ in range(10):
        obj_queue.append(bproc.loader.load_obj(str(obj)).pop())
        part = obj_queue[-1]

        print(obj.name)
        # remove '.obj'
        print('parts: ', parts)
        idx = parts.index(obj.name[:-4])
        part.set_cp("category_id", idx + 1)
        part.set_name(parts[idx])
        print('category_id =', part.get_cp("category_id"))
        print('Part Name =', part.get_name())
```

I have:

```
(base) mona@ada:~/BlenderProc2_Cobot/BlenderProc/CAD_model/models$ ls
total 2.0M
drwxrwxr-x 4 mona mona 4.0K Dec  5 13:32 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 1.8M Dec  6 10:06 abandoned_tank_farm_03_primary.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona 225K Dec  6 11:36 55917-700lf.obj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona  242 Dec  6 11:36 55917-700lf.mtl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona  990 Dec  6 13:01 brick_background.obj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mona mona  295 Dec  6 13:03 brick_background.mtl
drwxrwxr-x 2 mona mona 4.0K Dec  6 13:06 .
```

and

abandoned_tank_farm_03_primary.png

is

[image: abandoned_tank_farm_03_primary]